# How to fetch comments from mysql database without destroying my html tags

Tags: php, html

I want to give a little style for my comment section, here is the code without any css, but i want to give it some style

```
<div id="comments">
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<p>";
            echo $row['author'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['message'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['time'];
            echo "</p>";

        }

    } else {
        echo "there are no comments!";
    }
?>
</div>
<button>More comments</button>
```

and down here is my html section of which i want to appear while handling my php comments where USER, COMMENT and TIME are are stored in my database, here is the html, how can i echo the above variables into the below html tags ?

```
<div class="media response-info">
<div class="media-left response-text-left">
<a href="#">
<img class="media-object" src="images/c1.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<h5><a href="#">USER</a></h5>
</div>
<div class="media-body response-text-right">
<p>COMMENT</p>
<ul>
<li>TIME</li>
<li><a href="single.html">Reply</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply close the PHP tags. Remember, PHP in-itself is a templating language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
    <div id="comments">
   <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <div class="media response-info">
            <div class="media-left response-text-left">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="media-object" src="images/c1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <h5><a href="#"><?php echo $row['author']; ?></a></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body response-text-right">
            <p><?php  echo $row['message']; ?></p>
            <ul>
            <li><?php echo $row['time']; ?> </li>
            <li><a href="single.html">Reply</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>

<?php   }

    } else {
        echo "there are no comments!";
    }
?>
</div>
```

hope it will help you.